# How can PHP be forced to use the newest version of libcurl

Tags: php, apache, curl, libcurl

First, let me say that I am not sure if this is the right place to post this question. Perhaps a different "stack" entity would be better. If so, please point me in the right direction and I will move this question.

The question is a simple one. However, I have not found a simple answer. Right now my version of PHP (7.2) running under Apache is using libcurl version 58. However, I would like to use libcurl version 64. I downloaded the libcurl source and did a successful source build of version 64. However, when I run PHP I am still getting libcurl 58? What is wrong here? Thank you in advance.

As way of background, libcurl 58 returns an error code of 61 (in some cases) if it gets back a header with a content type of none. A content type of none is invalid and is actually a server bug. However, apparently this invalid content type has become commonplace and the newest versions of libcurl ignore it.

Comment: I believe you mean a Content-Encoding header with a `none` header value (ie not content-type).

Comment: Mr. Stenberg, you are almost certainly correct. The problem is with a Content-Encoding header, not a content-type header. Has this been fixed in libcurl version 64? I do understand that this is really a server bug, not a libcurl flaw.

Comment: From libcurl 7.59.0, `Content-Encoding: none` is treated the same as `identity`, which could be viewed as a bugfix. This is originally a server bug since `none` is not a valid content encoding, but so frequently used everywhere that curl has been adapted to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded the libcurl source and did a successful source build of version 64

After that you must install it on your system (and replace libcurl version 58).

And do this first on a test server before doing it in production.

Comment: user803422, thank you for your answer. However, I don't know how to install my new version of libcurl. What steps are required?